# How to deploy angular 4 (type-script) + node API application on iis?

Tags: node.js, angular, iis

I've developed an angular 4 application with node js API.I just wanted to deploy it on Internet Information Server.
I've deploy angular app on IIS,but how to manage with node API ?

Comment: I’m not sure what IIS is but why not deploy the static files from ng build?

Comment: @MikeTung : bcuz i wanna run this application locally , have u another way without IIS ? Plz provide related link or solution..

Answer (score 0):

Please check iisnode module by azure :
[Hosting node.js app on iis](https://github.com/Azure/iisnode/blob/master/README.md)